# Java android glide resize photo

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I want to resize an image and I use a glide. I load an image from file and I want to resize an image and save to this same file a resized image

```
public static void minimizeImageWithPicasso(Context context, final File file, int targetSize, Handler handler) {

final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(), options);

float ratio = Math.max(options.outWidth, options.outHeight) / (float) targetSize;

//don't scale image that is smaller than targetSize
if (ratio < 1) return;

int dstWidth = (int) (options.outWidth / ratio);
int dstHeight = (int) (options.outHeight / ratio);


Glide
        .with(context)
        .load(file)
        .asBitmap()
        .centerCrop()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .into(new FileTarget(file.getAbsolutePath(), dstWidth, dstHeight));
}
```

I did this but it doesn't convert a photo to file

Comment: Use this  `.apply(new RequestOptions().override(600, 200))` with `Glide` .

Comment: @RakeshKumar I have cannot resolved method apply

Comment: Have you imported `RequestOptions` class?

Comment: @RakeshKumar I cannot use method apply

Comment: Are you using glide 4.x ? or let me know which version you are using?

Comment: @RakeshKumar  i use 3.7.0 when I use 4.x  i can not save into file

Comment: try `.override(600,200)` only.

Comment: @RakeshKumar this should resize image         .into(new FileTarget(file.getAbsolutePath(), dstWidth, dstHeight));